# How to enable Copilot in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I've installed the Copilot extension and am trying to use it but this error shows up in output:

> 2024-03-29 14:20:07.471 [info] [auth] Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403
> 2024-03-29 14:20:07.529 [error] [auth] Extension activation failed: "No access to GitHub Copilot found. You are currently logged in as priyaanshusoni."
> 2024-03-29 14:53:07.125 [info] [auth] Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403

Comment: ["To use GitHub Copilot you must have an active GitHub Copilot subscription."](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/using-github-copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot#prerequisites-2) Do you just forget to subscribe?

Comment: Seems to me that your github account is missing a valid copilot token. I reached that conclusion through sheer deductive reasoning, by reading the error messages that you supplied.

Comment: Okayyy .. Understood !